# How to get the outputResources of a deployment using the fluent Resource Manager SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk, azure-fluent-api

When using the [GET Deployments endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/get#deploymentpropertiesextended) of the Azure REST API, it's possible to get details of a given deployment including the outputResources which lists the actual resources created from an ARM template deployment

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find an equivalent means of accessing the outputResources when using the Azure Resource Manager Fluent SDK.

I've tried using the following:

```
var deployments = ResourceManager.Authenticate(credentials)
.WithSubscription(subscriptionId)
.Deployments.ListByResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
.Where(x => x.Name == deploymentName)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
.First();
```

but this doesn't seem to allow me to get the details of the actual resources which were deployed.

These seem to be the only accessible properties of `deployment`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conducting a Deployment using the Azure SDK gives you back an `IDeployment` object, and the properties you're looking for are now nested pretty deeply.

All of the operations related to your deployment live under `IDeployment.DeploymentOperations`.  You can call `.List()` to get an enumerator and step through them.

Each `DeploymentOperations` object has some members you'll be interested in, the most useful to me are:

```
foreach(IDeploymentOperation op in deployment.DeploymentOperations.List())
{
    op.ProvisioningState // Completed, In Progress, Error
    op.StatusMessage // OK, Failed, etc
    op.TargetResource.Id // the fully qualified resource Id of your deployment
    op.TargetResource.ResourceName // the name of the new item
    op.TargetResource.ResourceType // the type of the new item, StorageAccount, Networking, etc
}
```

And to reiterate you'll find the Id, which is probably the most important under this path

```
op.TargetResource.Id // the fully qualified resource Id of your deployment
/subscriptions/abc123/resourcegroup/MycoolGroup123/storageAccount/abc123efg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) to get the detailed information of deployments.

1. Install Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package
2. Create an auth file as [AUTH.md](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md)
3. Sample

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate("C:\\Users\\v-linjji\\my.azureauth").WithDefaultSubscription();
       var deployments = azure.Deployments.ListByResourceGroup("JackWebApp");
       foreach(var deployment in deployments)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(deployment.Timestamp + " -> " + deployment.Name);

           foreach(var dependency in deployment.Dependencies)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(dependency.Id);
           }

           foreach(var operation in deployment.DeploymentOperations.List())
           {
               Console.WriteLine(operation.OperationId + " -> " + operation.StatusCode);
           }

           Console.WriteLine("Outputs:" + deployment.Outputs);

           Console.WriteLine();
       }

       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This field, `Outputs` is not the same property he is talking about.  `Outputs` are only filled in if you specify the optional `Outputs` node in an ARM template.  The outPutResources field, meanwhile, has a list of all of the generated Resource URIs and is similar to what you see in the console after an Arm Deployment.